# Auto-listing sub and sub-sub domains in Apache

Tags: subdomain, apache-2.2, wildcard-subdomain

**Preamble**

At work, I'll be migrating our server from a WAMP box to a LAMP box and with my knowledge of Apache and wildcard domains, we're hoping to use client.ourtestserver.com instead of our current test.ourtestserver.com/client/project_id

Of course, management wants the project_id in the URL for accounting, billing and organizational purposes, so they want to use project_id.client.ourtestserver.com or client.ourtestserver.com/project_id.

Problem is, the developers and project managers like the short name to develop with (client.ourtestserver.com), so there's a conflict.

**My Question**

Is there a way for Apache to automatically list a sub-domain's sub-sub-domains, such as client.ourtestserver.com listing (through a simple directory listing or of the like) sub-sub domains such as 1234.client.ourtestserver.com, 1235.client.ourtestserver.com, 3452.client.ourtestserver.com ??

That way we can point a client to client.ourtestserver.com (which is easier to say over the phone) and have them click on their project_id.

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Running `httpd -S` will list all VirtualHost and NameVirtualHosts for an apache configuration. However if you are using the wildcard feature, I believe the only authoritative source for this information is the DNS server for the "ourtestserver.com" zone. Of course, you can do analysis of the access logs, provided that you have `%{Host}i` in your LogFormat, but that will only provide sub-sub-domains that have been accessed before.